# Send case-insensitive regex to mongoose over JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sending a query to my server from JavaScript as a JSON document. This query should contain a regular expression to be used by Mongoose when finding my documents.

```
{
  query: {
    foo: "^bar"
  }
}
```

The query above works fine, but I want it to be case-sensitive.

```
{
  query: {
    foo: "/^bar/i"
  }
}
```

Does *not* work (I get a `CastError`). I can't send a RegEx without quotes, because this is JSON.

Is there a way I can get this to work without any server-side modification?

Comment: `"foo": /bar/i` or `"foo": { "$regex": "bar", "$options": "i" }` or even `"foo": { "$regex": /bar/, "$options": "i" }`. Well documented. See: [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). And if you are getting a `"Cast Error"` from Mongoose then that means you are actually trying to "store" the data and not issue a query. BTW Regex **is** a valid BSON type, so you **can** even store it as such in a MongoDB document.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm transmitting this over REST. So JSON. Not BSON. The `$options` did work, so cheers, I guess. Not sure what you have against me asking a question that can be answered by docs - that's 50% of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Blakes Seven's answer in the comments above, the `$options` field can be used as a substitute for typical RegEx flags.

```
Schema.find({"foo": { "$regex": "bar", "$options": "i" });
```